# Trouble writing action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**UPDATE**

I have an action in my Miniatures model called `set_gold_and_silver`.

I want my Users model to run it when a User is destroyed, so I have `before_destroy :set_gold_and_silver` in my User model.

A User has many Imagevotes. Before destroy I need to delete those Imagevotes and then run `set_gold_and_silver` on all the Miniatures that those imagevotes pertained to.

This is what I've got so far and I'm currently getting `undefined method 'miniatures'`.

It's not clear to me whether I am caching self.imagevotes or whether they are just deleted and then I get the error because they no longer exist?

```
def set_gold_and_silver
   votes = self.imagevotes
   self.imagevotes.destroy
   votes.miniatures.uniq.each(&:set_gold_and_silver)
end
```

My models

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
  has_many :collections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :miniatures, through: :collections

  has_many :imagevotes, foreign_key: "voted_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :imagevotes, foreign_key: "voter_id", dependent: :destroy
  before_destroy :set_gold_and_silver

  def set_gold_and_silver
    my_collections = self.collections.each
    their_miniatures = collection.miniature.uniq
    my_collections.their_miniatures.each(&:set_gold_and_silver)
  end


end
```

**Miniature**

```
class Miniature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :collections
  has_many :imagevotes, dependent: :destroy

  def set_gold_and_silver
    wipe = self.collections.all
    wipe.each {|s| s.update_attributes :is_gold => false, :is_silver => false}
    top_collections = self.collections.limit(4)
    gold = top_collections.shift 
    gold.update_attribute :is_gold, true if gold
    top_collections.each {|s| s.update_attribute :is_silver, true}
  end
end
```

**Collection**

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('imagevotes_count DESC')
  belongs_to :miniature
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :imagevotes, dependent: :destroy

end
```

**Imagevote**

```
class Imagevote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :collection, :counter_cache => true
    belongs_to :voter, class_name: "User", :counter_cache => "voted_count"
    belongs_to :voted, class_name: "User", :counter_cache => "vote_count"
    belongs_to :miniature

    after_create :set_gold_and_silver
    after_update :set_gold_and_silver

    def set_gold_and_silver
        self.miniature.set_gold_and_silver
    end

end
```

Comment: You need to update your question with pseudocode of models User, Miniature, Collection including has/belongs properties and before/after filters. It's good that you created separate question, but still it's needed even there, and definitely here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your code simpler:

```
class Miniature < ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_gold_and_silver
    self.collections.update_all("is_gold = false, is_silver = false")
    top_collections = self.collections.limit(4)
    gold = top_collections.shift 
    gold.update_attribute :is_gold, true if gold
    top_collections.each {|s| s.update_attribute :is_silver, true}
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_gold_and_silver
    self.miniatures.uniq.each(&:set_gold_and_silver)
  end
end
```

you have has_many :miniatures, through: :collections so you don't need to work with collections to get minuatures.

And for now your code not working because everything still there *before destroy*. It need to be done after, when everything depended to user removed. And also as it seems for me you need to remove imagevotes in user destroy and set_gold_and_silver only after that. For now it's not done, so gold and silver stays.

Comment: Thanks for the code simplifying. I thought that if I did it after_destroy I would not be able to find the User.collections that needed to be set_gold_and_silver?

Comment: So in this case you need to find all miniatures belongs to user in before_destroy, destroy all imagevotes that belongs to our user, and call set_gold on them.

Comment: Yes. For the second step imagevotes will be destroyed automatically because they are dependent and will be destroyed with the User right? So I just need the before and after destroy actions?

Comment: To made this simpler, you just need to replace dependent: destroy with before_destroy. This'll allow you to work with miniatures without need of update all of them, not only our user ones.

Comment: I don't understand how you can replace dependent: destroy before before_destroy. You mean in the line starting has_many?

Comment: Remove dependent destroy, and destroy records by hands in before_destroy filter of parent where you remove dependent destroy. In this case you can resolve links on user.collections. I am already write about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616983/trouble-writing-action/22617963?noredirect=1#comment34441982_22617963).

Comment: I have been working on this more and have a problem. before destroy I need to run self.imagevotes.delte but I then need to run self.imagevotes.miniatures(&:set_gold_and_silver) but by that point self.imagevotes will be nil. Can this be fixed?

Comment: You need to collect all miniatures from imagevotes for deletion. @miniatures = self.imagevotes.map(&:miniature).uniq. After that you need to destroy imagevotes and call @miniatures.each(&:set_gold_and_silver) after that.

Comment: That's it that's it! Thank you Sergey. You are a hero.